# JavaScript -JUnk data is displaying after focus out from a field

Tags: javascript

I have used onfocusout event and i have called a method to do some action.if i again focus on the same field and delete the output from the method i called,dummy data is filling in the field instead of empty field.Please help with this issue.

Comment: can you paste your code here or a plunker if possible?

Comment: remove the `placeholder=value` attribute

Comment: "_Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") __must include__ the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and __the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself__. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]._"